# cannot import typed.js, jQuery and google-fonts from node_modules

Tags: jquery, npm, node-modules, google-fonts, typedjs

I have used typed.js, jQuery and google-fonts in my web page. I have installed them using npm. But the problem is i cant figure out what files to import to make them work. This is how i have imported these files and is not working.

jQuery as

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

typed.js as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/typed.js/src/typed.js"></script>
```

In the browser's console panel it shows

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Typed is not defined
    <anonymous> http://localhost:1234/:168
localhost:1234:168:13
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    <anonymous> http://localhost:1234/:175
```

Everything works perfectly without any error when i use a CDN for each of them

Here is the use of typed.js

```
<h1 id="h1"><span class="type"></span></h1>

<script>
    var typed = new Typed('.type', {
        strings: ['<span class="text-primary">....</span>', '<span class="text-success">....</span>',],
        loop: true,
        backSpeed: 50,
        typeSpeed: 125,

    });
</script>
```

the use of jQuery

```
 <h3 class="quotes">....</h3>
 <h3 class="quotes">....</h3>


<script>
    (jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var quotes = $("h3");
        var quoteIndex = 0;
        var color =  509 ;
        function showNextQuote() {
            ++quoteIndex;
            //alert(quoteIndex);
            var x = quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length);
            //console.log(x);
            var newcolor =  color * Math.random(1999) ;
            x.css("color","#" + newcolor).fadeIn(600)
                .delay(750)
                .fadeOut(600, showNextQuote);
        }
        showNextQuote();
    }));
</script>
```

in case of google-fonts i cant find a single css file to import from node_modules.
Also what is the correct place to put the link of these files

i will be glad if you can help

Comment: Importing both `jquery` and `jquery.slim` is not logical and will not work correctly. Please edit the question to show your usage of the `JQuery` and `Typed` globals

Comment: @AluanHaddad I have updated the use of jQuery and typed.js. Please see if it helps